# Under numbered? How to describe a team that doesn't have enough members?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Under numbered? How to describe a team that doesn't have enough members? Any adjective or a short phrase?

Comment: What about _under-membered_ ?.

Comment: Under strength?

Comment: I'd say "incomplete".

Comment: Isn't *short* the standard term? That's not at all the same as *three men short* but I thought *a short team* was a common phrase…

Comment: Avoid posting word or phrase requests without: (i) your criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 2):

You can say they're ***[short-handed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shorthanded)***:

> : having, working with, or done with fewer than the regular or necessary number of people
>   <sub>from *[m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shorthanded)*</sub>

Comment: You beat me to that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Sports teams are "undermanned," apparently even [women's teams.](https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&hl=de-de&ei=az87Wr6mJcvSwQKfvJLwAQ&sjs=1&q=women%27s%20team%20undermanned&oq=women%27s%20team%20undermanned&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...5397.19720.0.21087.41.40.0.1.1.0.326.7121.1j23j13j2.39.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..16.23.4781.3..0j41j0i131k1j0i10k1j0i19k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j30i10k1j33i160k1j33i21k1.0.nbn4ztyRLXo)

Other kinds of teams or groups can be "understaffed."